# GPU Acceleration expectation

Tags: matlab, gpu

I have a code that does some havey computing on 3D arrays. The code is optimized to work on GPU. The 3D array is basically a set of 2D arrays. Each one is stored in a page of the 3D array.

For simplicity, let us consider the whole code is:

```
A = rand(512,512,100,'gpuArray');
B = fftshift(fftshift(fft2(fftshift(fftshift(A,1),2)),1),2);
```

Where 512*512 is each 2D array dimensions and the 100 is the number of those 2D arrays.

On nVidia GTX 1060, it takes `x millisecond` to be computed.

I tried to change the 2D array size to `256*256` or `128*128`, no performance enhancement would be noticed. The new time is around `0.9*x milliseconds`.

This behavior is expected since, AFAIK, smaller array will not utilize GPU enough and many cores will be IDLE. So, no real gain here.

**My question:**

If I bought better GPU such as 1080ti or the new 2080ti (seems not available now), would I get a real performance enhancement? I mean since I did not even utilize the whole 1060 capability, would a better GPU make a real difference?

I could think that the clock speed may make a difference. However, I am not sure how much this enhancement would be significant.

One benefit of a better GPU is the bigger memory which will let me do the process on 1024*1024 (which I can not do on the 1060 GPU). However, this is not my main concern.

Comment: Why do you say you are not using all the GPUs capacity? Memory you mean? But yes, the computation speed is related mostly to the clock speed, I'd expect you to see an improvemenet with a better GPU. but mabe just 1.1*x or 1.2*x

Comment: each gpu has a GFLOP computation power which you could compare , plus various parameter like memory clock , bandwidth etc , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Nvidia_graphics_processing_units

Comment: another method is to convert your array from  double to single which greatly affect the speed

Comment: I'm not getting the same results on a TITAN X (Pascal). The initial execution time is very slow, about 2.5 minutes. Subsequent executions of the code are substantially faster, running your snippet 1000 times I get an average of 20.4 ms and changing the array size to 128x128x100 the average drops to 2.3 ms.

Comment: Thanks for all comments. @jodag did compute your average including the initial call or without it?

Comment: My timing did not include the initial call and only considered the second line of the code. Inside the loop looked something like `A=...; tic; B=...; total = total + toc;` so only the fft line was considered.

Comment: If it will help I also have access to systems with Quadro P6000, 1080Ti, TITAN X (Maxwell), and Tesla K40. They aren't being used this weekend so I can run some timing experiments on those if you want. Unfortunately they all have slightly different specs (CPU+RAM) so not sure how helpful it will be.

Comment: @jodag: did you set `fftw('planner','measure');` earlier in your testing session? This will initiate an algorithm that tries to determine the optimal FFT algorithm for a certain task, which will increase the runtime of the first FFT call substantially. This could be the reason why your first call took substantially longer.

Comment: @jodag I thank you very much! I am really very eager to know the results on 1080 ti. However, I do not want to bother you. If you could find sometime to do a fast try on the 1080 ti without getting you bust, I would be very grateful. Thank you!